# Locking and thread safe around streaming API

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking, ienumerable

Probably a fairly simple question but I want to know the best practice in making the code thread safe.

I am using an external non thread-safe API within a mutli-threaded environment.

It returns an `IEnumerable<ApiDto>`.
I then map each of the ApiDto to our application's DTO: **MyDto**.

How do I ensure that the code is thread-safe?

For example:

This is my class that gets items from API

```
public class ApiRepo
{
    private IApi api;
    public ApiRepo()
    {
        api=new Api("url");
    }
    public IEnumerable<MyDto> GetItems()
    {
        var apiDtos = api.GetNonThreadSafeItems();
        foreach(var apiDto in apiDtos)
        {
           var myDto = new MyDto(apiDto.Name);  
           yield return myDto;
        }

    }

}
```

This is my client application.
Multiple instances of Client are created and data is retrieved from the API.

```
public class Client
{
    public void GetData()
    {
        var items = new ApiRepo().GetItems().ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(items.Count);
    }
}
```

Should I put a lock within Client.GetData() or is there any better way to make the code thread-safe?

Comment: It is a third party library and in the documentation, it says "This Api is not thread safe".

Comment: The object is documented as not safe.  **Unless there is also documentation on how to make it safe, you don't know how to make it safe**.  There are some objects which cannot be made safe to run on multiple threads at all.

Comment: For example, consider two common ways of using not-threadsafe objects in a threadsafe manner.  The "apartment" system is: make as many instances of the object as you want, but only call the object's methods on the thread that created the object.  **Not every object is safe for apartment threading**.  The "rental" system is: make as many instances of the object as you want, but arrange so that only one thread accesses an individual object at any one time.  **Not every object is safe for rental threading**.  You have to know the details of the object!

Comment: For example, consider an object that contains a reference to another object of its same kind, and you try to protect the objects via locks.  Objects Foo and Bar both reference object Blah. You arrange via locks that Foo is only ever used from one thread and Bar is only ever used from one thread, but **nothing is stopping both Foo and Bar from accessing Blah on two different threads**, and now you're unsafe. **You have to know ALL of the implementation details of the class, AND THEY MUST NEVER CHANGE in order to know that your locks are correct!** That's why programming with locks is hard.

Comment: You should trust the documentation. The object isn't threadsafe. **So don't use it from multiple threads.**

Comment: Ok... Remember the application is big and it creates multiple instances of client, is it best to add lock within its Getdata method so it does ToList within a lock or within ApiRepo.GetItems method because it's Ienumerable.

Answer (score -1):

An API is 'not thread safe' means it operate base on some golbal resource whitout synchronize mechanism. So, in order to get correct result form the API, your need to make sure only one thread call it at one time. Base on your sample, most easy way to do that is like

```
public class ApiRepo
{
    static private object theLock = new object();
    private IApi api;

    public ApiRepo()
    {
        api=new Api("url");
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyDto> GetItems()
    {
        IEnumerable<ApiDto> apiDtos = null;
        lock(theLock)
        {
            apiDtos = api.GetNonThreadSafeItems();
        }
        foreach(var apiDto in apiDtos)
        {
           var myDto = new MyDto(apiDto.Name);  
           yield return myDto;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The proposal here is to use a single global lock to get a collection of the objects, but the supposition is that the objects *themselves* are not threadsafe, not just the API that gets them.  So this code is not threadsafe, and since it uses a global lock, it's has bad performance in contention scenarios.

Comment: Moreover, we do not know that the object that *is* locked is safe for this kind of concurrency.  You've ensured that every instance of `Api` accessed via this class is done so under a lock, but it is therefore possible that the same object gets accessed on two different threads at two different times. This is the *rental threaded* model, but suppose the underlying object is only *apartment threaded* safe; what happens then?  **The object can crash when used**, and in fact many apartment threaded objects deliberately crash in this situation.

Comment: @EricLippert Base on the question and the sample code, it is hard to be believe that owner of this post wanted to secure all thing in one lock statement. And also, thread safy only focus on  race conditions of shared resource accessing. If a class or a library use single-thread apartment model to avoid race condition, it only means that the class or the classes belong to the library can not  access from multi-thread environment, and the documents have to mention it and not just say they are not thread saft.

Comment: Any way, not use a api from multi thread just because it is not thread safe is not smart to me.